# Is Selenium 2 WebDriver JavaDoc API available offline?

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, java, documentation

Can I get a offline copy/archive of Selenium Webdriver Javadoc API which is available [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html) so that I can bind the same to my Eclipse IDE for offline use?

A ready-made HTML archive will be appreciated instead of any suggestion to copy the entire site using any Web-spider software :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in git so you could do a sparse checkout to get the JavaDoc part of the repo only.  This blog post about sparse checkouts goes through it in a reasonable amount of detail:

http://blog.quilitz.de/2010/03/checkout-sub-directories-in-git-sparse-checkouts/comment-page-1/#comment-3146

Or you could download them from maven central:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-server/2.32.0/